# AMD Radeon Vega Graphics Drivers for Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, 19.10

I have an Acer Aspire 3 Laptop which has a AMD Ryzen™ 3 2200U processor and an AMD Radeon Vega Graphics Card. I am currently using Ubuntu 19.10 but I am experiencing many issues due to the lack of support for the Graphics Card.

Problems I'm having:

- The change display option randomly pops up on the screen.
- I am unable to change the brightness of the screen.
- Programs randomly lags.
- Certain graphical effects are laggy.
- Unable to use graphical boot screens (plymouth themes).

I have been searching and found the AMDGPU graphics driver but I have only found it for 19.04 but not 19.10.

Does anyone know where and how I an obtain and install the drivers for my graphics card?

Comment: AMD cards use open source drivers, so there should be nothing extra to install. The drivers are already included in Ubuntu 19.10. The AMDGPU Pro drivers add some proprietary parts on top of that, but as 19.10 was just released, may not be available for it yet. It might be more helpful if you describe exactly what issues you're seeing, instead.

Comment: @dobey I updated my question.

Comment: Solution for 19.10 is here : https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-19.10-Radeon-RX-5700 Works for my 3500u Ryzen Mobile with Vega RX as well.